# Installing a ceiling fan/light with a receiver and two wall switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have the following ceiling light/fan combo that I’m going to install (Ashby Park ceiling fan [Instructions](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/39/398b80c0-99cf-459b-956d-0b6762c9456c.pdf)) in a bedroom that has two light switches. One for the light and one for a fan. However, due to the way this fan has a receiver and the way the receiver is set up, is it even possible to have the switches on the wall control this the way I’d like it to?

Also, here’s the light switch setup [image: switch setup]

Comment: It's a little unclear what's going on in this picture. Can you take another with a better look into the box itself? Also, can you take a picture of the wires going into the existing junction box on the ceiling? It appears your fan only requires a single hot, so your wall switch would turn everything on or off. Separate light and fan controls would come from your phone, according to the installation guide

Comment: For the pic above, there’s a white/black wire coming in from the bottom right which connects to the switch on the right. The (hot) wire is partial stripped mid way through so that it can loop through the right switch and then connect to the one on the left on the bottom. The wire coming in from the top right has red/black/white and goes up from here to the ceiling box where those 3 wires(+ ground) come out of.

Comment: This was here when we bought the house and the switch on the right (pic above) currently does nothing, while the one on the left turns on the basic light that is currently in the room.

Comment: Is it the only light in the room, or is there another light also controlled by a switch in the normal location (e.g. near the door)?

Comment: Yes, it’s the only light in the room. There’s another single switch to the left of those two that controls the light in the closet.

Comment: @ACanadianCoder are you wedded to the reciever that came to your fan, or are you open to considering different options?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I’m open to whatever

Comment: @ACanadianCoder -- is returning the fan and getting a different one an option for that matter?  It seems that you have one of those wacky DC fans that requires a proprietary control to work...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yeah, realized that too late. We bought this fan months ago and I just ended up installing it the way it’s supposed to be installed. The second switch will continue to do nothing at all. We have another bedroom that I’m buying another fan for that will have a pull string for each light/fan so that both switches will work for it.

Comment: It sounds like you just connected one of the switches as I expected from my initial comment. If you want, you can answer the question yourself with the actual installation and accept that answer. Otherwise, I could provide one so we can resolve the open question